Onsager-Machlup functional and the Boltzmann distribution
I've been looking into path integral representations of stochastic processes lately and came across the Onsager-Machlup functional description of the Langevin equation. In the overdamped case, where the Langevin equation reads $$0=-\gamma \dot{x} - \frac{d V}{dx} - \eta{t}$$ with $\gamma$ the friction, $\eta$ the Gaussian white noise, and mass assumed to be unity, the corresponding Onsager-Machlup action functional is $$S[x(s)] = \frac{\Delta V}{\gamma} + \frac{1}{2} \int \limits_0^t ds [\dot{x}^2 + (F/\gamma)^2 + \frac{2D}{\gamma} F']$$ where $F=-\frac{d V}{dx}$ is the force, $\Delta V$ is the change in potential between the start and end points of the trajectory, and $D=k_BT/\gamma$ is the diffusion constant.
In this formalism, the path integral representation of the probability of a trajectory starting at $x_i$ and ending at $x_f$ after time $t$ is
$$P(x_f|x_i,t) = \int Dx(s) e ^{-S[x(s)]/2D}.$$
I was wondering how one can see that the equilibrium probability distribution sampled by the Langevin equation, as we know it to be, is the Boltzmann distribution $\propto e ^{-\beta V(x)}$?
In field theory, I've seen the approach taken wherein one considers passing from a reference position (say 0) to position $x$ after imaginary time $\tau$, $P(x|0,\tau)$  in order to extract the equilibrium distribution at a given temperature. Could
Is there a known way to pass to the Fokker-Planck equation from the Onsager-Machlup functional perhaps, which would allow one to see the equivalence to the usual Fokker-Planck equation for the overdamped Langevin equation?

Is this from a reference? Which page?

Yeah, there are a few references but these two are the main ones which I am referring to: https://doi.org/10.1063/1.3372802 and https://doi.org/10.1021/jp0751458 (pages 2 and 1 respectively) along with the original paper by Onsager and Machlup https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.91.1505 where they introduced the functional.

See eq. 14 of the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0605548 although it seems that they just prove it for a quadratic potential.. And of course they assume that the system is ergodic (the steady state solution is unique and independent on the initial condition)

But basically, the onsager machlup gives you the propagator. The convolution of the propagator with an initial distribution gives you the time evolution of the probability distribution (might as well chose a dirac delta as an initial distribution!). Then you just have to look at the large time value of this distribution of probability to obtain the steady state distribution. In the paper I linked it is done for a quadratic potential. I agree that it might be more complex with more complicated potential. It starts to be interesting for non equilibrium scenarios!

Hi, thanks a lot - this is exactly the type of thing I'm looking for. I actually came across that paper a little bit ago when I was trawling around and should have paid more attention to their approach. Do you know how exactly they go from eqns 9,10 and 11 to equation 11? It seems like you could do something similar to what is done for the HO propagator in the path integral representation of QM perhaps but they split the path integration up into discrete timesteps which I can't see how exactly they will use. I would try to use the same approach for general $U(x)$ (I guess it must be possible).

Also, that's a very nice summary regarding propagator->convolution with initial distribution->consider large time behaviour to obtain the steady state. Thanks again!

Ah, actually, they provide further information in the appendix for how they arrive at that result. Will check that out!

@aQuarkyName It seems that it's a problem a bit too difficult to tackle directly from the path integral. I tried the large time behavior of the propagator or looking if the convolution of an infinitesimal time propagator with the expectzd equilibrium distribution would leave it invariant but even this seems too complicated to obtain. By passing to the Folker Planck equation derived from the action you can of course directly prove it...

... see https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~pruess/publications/noneq_slides.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi33KHT7reFAxUM-gIHHUnjDMkQFnoECBIQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0KwnfoWbE19_zbet9tVXlv starting at slide 67. I would be curious to know if for arbitrary potential we can do anything without defining a FP equation and looking at the stationnary state.

@Syrocco Hey, thanks again for another nice reference (found quite a bit of useful stuff in those slides). Also, those are pretty nice ideas regarding use of the propagator. Shame that it doesn't seem to help. I'm not sure how to proceed with the same approach as  arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0605548 in the case of a general potential (I don't think this really gives a viable route for general V(x)). Also very curious to know if there is anything that can be done without resorting to the FP equation so will keep searching around and let you know if I come across anything promising.

One can find the extremum trajectory and the quadratic fluctuations around it - by usual procedure of varying action. (If I am not mistaken, this leads directly to Newton equations with damping.) This is easily done for a potential with a single minimum it is easily done. However, in the case of multiple minima one needs to resort to instantons and stuff like that... which is usually not easier than solving the Fokker-Planck equation. Onsager-Machlup is handy for numerical simulations using MCMC.
It is worth digging up old papers on reaction-diffusuon theory. This review could be a useful departing point: Rev. Mod. Phys. 62, 251 (1990) - Reaction-rate theory: fifty years after Kramers

Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. So you think that for formal manipulations, the OM action isn't overly useful for getting to equilibrium probability distributions and it is more useful as a numerical tool? That does seem to be the case as I can't find much in the way of literature that pursues the former. It's just that it seems like one should be able to do something similar to what is done in QFT with the Euclidian action to obtain the (diagonal of) the density matrix and therefore the probability distribution of the position.
I'll have a read of the reference you provide, thank you!
